# C# - implementation of method which is using generic types

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I am creating a `MDI form` and I have a method that loads the different forms. Now I need to make a little modification - I need to add functionality that calls one child form from within another child form.

Because I need this in several different places I made a new class from who all the classes that need this functionality inherits. I want to make it work with generic types so I can pass every form class that I may need like `LoadAForm(MyForm1)` or `LoadAForm(MyForm2)` and so on.. I hope I it's clear what I want as final result.

I tried this:

```
protected void LoadAForm<T>(ref T sender)
{
    MainForm frm = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
    T temp;
    if (frm != null)
    {
        sender  = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<temp>(frm, true);
        sender.MdiParent = frm;
        sender.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        sender.Show();
    }
}
```

which doesn't work. But I have almost no experience with generics even more when they are used in methods, so I don't know how to go on.

What I get as an error using this syntax is `The type or namespace "temp" could not be found...". I'm not even sure that this is the way to do it.`GetInstance<>` has to take an argument of the same type as the type of the form I'm calling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the *type* parameter, not the variable name:

```
sender = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<T>(frm, true);
```

Also, to ensure that `T` is valid (as your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642456/c-sharp-implementation-of-method-which-is-using-generic-types/14642488#comment20457073_14642488) suggests) you will need to constrain it:

```
protected void LoadAForm<T>(ref T sender) where T : Form
```

Comment: I tried this but get this error `The type T can not be used as type parameter "T" in the generic type of method...There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from "T" to "System.Windows.Forms.Form`

Comment: @Leron - You need to add a type constraint on the method, so `T` can only derive from `Form`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need generics here. I think you could easier work by simply using `Form` as the concrete type:

```
protected void LoadAForm(ref Form sender)
{
    MainForm frm = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
    Form temp;
    if (frm != null)
    {
        sender  = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance(frm, true);
        sender.MdiParent = frm;
        sender.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        sender.Show();
    }
}
```